# Awesomium WebControl 1.7.5.1 зависает

Tags: javascript, c#, async-await, awesomium

**Есть программа, которая создает несколько (2-8) Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl в Form'е (используется Awesomium 1.7.5.1)**

Необходимо постоянно получать значение InnerHTML каждого WebControl, перезагружать страницу `webControl.Source = "https://someurl.com/"`, а также осуществлять ввод в поля `<input>` и нажимать на кнопки `element.click()`.

**Есть две проблемы, при которых WebControl зависает и с которыми я не могу разобраться:**

1. Спустя некоторое время работы программы метод `webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(script)` возвращает значение `result.IsUndefined` и `webControl.GetLastError()` выдает значение `Awesomium.Core.Error.TimedOut`. Я пробовал менять значение 
   `webControl.SynchronousMessageTimeout` (сделал его `= 10000`мс), но баг остался. Причем несколько раз после этой ошибки работа продолжается исправно, но в очередной раз `webControl` зависает, остальные `webControl` продолжают исправно работать еще в течении нескольких минут, затем зависает вся форма, в которой находятся эти `webControl`.
2. Если используемый сайт большой (не могу указать размеры, просто заметил, что, если имеется 10-20 записей некоторого списка на сайте, то все работает, если 50-100, то появляется эта проблема), зависает на методе `browser.Source = new Uri(url)`, причем события `LoadingFrameComplete` и `DocumentReady` отрабатывают, но `WebControl` остается заблокированным (вызов перезагрузки страницы происходит из другого потока по событию таймера, в котором ставится `webControl.CmdComplete = false`, а при завершении работы `webControl.NavigateAsync(url)` возвращается обратно `webBrowser.CmdComplete = true`). При последующих проходах таймера `webBrowser.CmdComplete == false` долгое время (от нескольких секунд до десятков минут, хотя визуально страница давно загрузилась, работает и события загрузки отработали). И такое происходит только с несколькими webControl, необязательно со всеми. Обычно из четырех `webControl` один-два работают, остальные виснут (в самом начале). Через какое-то время зависание проходит, затем снова появляется (возможно уже на изначально работающих `webControl`).

Изначально программа написана с использованием движка `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` и она отлично работает без багов. Но появилась необходимость использовать авторизацию на одном и том же сайте одновременно разных пользователей. Для этих целей решил переписать ее под Awesomium. Поэтому проблема скорее всего в особенностях `Awesomium`, использовании методов навигации и/или исполнения javascript'a, а не в алгоритмах самой программы.

Сразу скажу, что использование браузерного движка необходимо, поэтому предлагать `WebRequest` не нужно.

`webControl` создается в классе-обертке `AwesomiumWebBrowserControl`. Методы класса-обертки:

```
//...
public AwesomeWebBrowserControl(string id)
{
    //...
    // инициализайция WebControl browser
    // для каждого WebControl используется отдельная сессия и куки
    string sess_path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\sessions";
    string acc_path = "\\" + id;
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(sess_path + acc_path)) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sess_path + acc_path);

    Awesomium.Core.WebPreferences wp = Awesomium.Core.WebPreferences.Default;
    wp.EnableGPUAcceleration = true;
    Awesomium.Core.WebSession session = Awesomium.Core.WebCore.CreateWebSession(sess_path + acc_path, wp);

    browser = new WebControl() 
    {
        WebSession = session,
        SynchronousMessageTimeout = 10000,
        Name = id
        //...
    };
    //...
}
//...
public Awesomium.Core.JSValue ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(string script)
{
    const string METHOD_NAME = "ExecuteJavascriptWithResult";
    try
    {
        if (IsReady()) return browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(script);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Program.CalcException(CLASS_NAME + "." + METHOD_NAME, ex);
    }
    return Awesomium.Core.JSValue.Null;
}
public string Html()
{
    const string METHOD_NAME = "Html";
    try
    {
        var html_nodes = (Awesomium.Core.JSObject)ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')");
        if (html_nodes["length"] != 1) return null;

        var html_node = (Awesomium.Core.JSObject)html_nodes.Invoke("item", 0);
        HtmlRAM = html_node["innerHTML"]; // string HtmlRAM - определено в AwesomeWebBrowserControl

        return HtmlRAM;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Program.CalcException(CLASS_NAME + "." + METHOD_NAME, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
public Awesomium.Core.JSValue Document()
{
    const string METHOD_NAME = "Document";
    try
    {
        return ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Program.CalcException(CLASS_NAME + "." + METHOD_NAME, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
//...
bool loading_frame_complete = true;
bool document_ready = true;
bool acquire_window = true;
public bool IsReady()
{
    if (loading_frame_complete &&
        document_ready &&
        browser.IsDocumentReady &&
        browser.IsLive &&
        !browser.IsLoading &&
        !browser.IsNavigating &&
        !browser.IsCrashed &&
        !browser.IsDisposed)
    {
        Awesomium.Core.JSValue jv_window = AcquireWindow();
        if (jv_window.IsUndefined) acquire_window = false;
        else acquire_window = true;

        return acquire_window;
    }
    else return false;
}
public async Task NavigateAsync(string url)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsNavigation = null;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsReady = null;

    browser.LoadingFrameComplete += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (tcsNavigation.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;
        if (e.IsMainFrame)
        {
            loading_frame_complete = true;
            tcsNavigation.SetResult(true);
        }
    };

    browser.DocumentReady += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (tcsReady.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;

        document_ready = true;
        tcsReady.SetResult(true);
    };

    tcsNavigation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tcsReady = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    loading_frame_complete = false;
    document_ready = false;

    browser.Source = new Uri(url);

    await tcsNavigation.Task;
    await tcsReady.Task;
}
private Awesomium.Core.JSValue AcquireWindow()
{
    // взято с http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/4784/workaround-for-executejavascriptwithresult.html
    // на ход работы никак не влияет, используется для проверки ошибок
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch methodStopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Awesomium.Core.JSValue windowValue = this.browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window");
    while (windowValue.IsUndefined && (methodStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 3000))
    {
        Program.WriteLine("Failed to acquire Javascript global window object. Probably a bug in the Awesomium framwork. Try again for a while");
        Awesomium.Core.Error lastError = browser.GetLastError();
        if (lastError != Awesomium.Core.Error.None)
        {
            switch (lastError)
            {
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.TimedOut:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was TimedOut");
                    break;
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.ConnectionGone:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was ConnectionGone");
                    break;
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.WebViewGone:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was WebViewGone");
                    break;
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.ObjectGone:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was ObjectGone, that is object no longer exiet?");
                    break;
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.BadParameters:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was BadParameters?");
                    break;
                case Awesomium.Core.Error.Generic:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was Generic, we don't know what happened");
                    break;
                default:
                    Program.WriteLine("Cause of failure was unknown error code");
                    break;
            }
        }
        windowValue = this.browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window");
    }
    if (windowValue.IsUndefined)
    {
        Program.WriteLine("Map has not been properly loaded. Request for interaction with map rejected to avoid crash in Windows Forms");
    }
    return windowValue;
}
//...
```

вызов перезагрузки страницы и исполнения скриптов осуществляется из обработчика таймера потока `Form` с `WebControl`'ами. Ниже показаны типовые примеры использования навигации и исполнения `javascript`:

```
await whc.NavigateAsync(url);

public void FocusIntern(bool must_focus = false)
{
    const string MethodName = "FocusIntern";
    if ((AutoFocus && (DateTime.Now - lastFocus).TotalSeconds >= secFocus) || must_focus)
    {
        using (dynamic wdoc = Document())
        {
            if (wdoc != null) wdoc.focus();
        }
        lastFocus = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public static async Task<RetVal<bool>> AuthInternAsync(AwesomeWebBrowserControl whc, string[] auth_data)
{
    const string MethodName = "AuthInternAsync";
    try
    {
        using ( dynamic result = (JSObject)whc.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(Js.Auth(auth_data[0], auth_data[1])))
        {
            if (result.error) return RetVal<bool>.ErrorMessage(Name + "." + MethodName + ": <" + result.message + ">");
        }

        return new RetVal<bool>(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Program.CalcException(Name + "." + MethodName, e);
    }
    return RetVal<bool>.ErrorMessage(Name + "." + MethodName + ": <Exception>");
}

// из класса Js
public static string Auth(string name, string password)
{
    // метод генерации скрипта авторизации
    const string MethodName = "Auth";
    return @"(
        function() {
            var res = {};
            res.error = true;
            res.message = 'undefined';

            try {
                // здесь javascript код авторизации на сайте
                // если авторизация удалась 
                    res.error = false;
                // иначе 
                {
                    res.error = true;
                    res.message = 'some message';
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                res.message = '" + ClassName + "." + MethodName + @": <' + e.name + ':' + e.message + '>';
            }

            return res;
        })();";
}
```

есть и другие методы (`LogoutInternAsync` и пр.), но они все построены по типу `AuthInternAsync`.

Вывод перед зависанием формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любые предположения и предложения буду проверять и комментировать, я очень заинтересован в скорейшем решении своего вопроса.

Если нужно больше кода, пишите - добавлю.

Comment: Что-то я внутри `AuthInternAsync` не вижу `await`...

Comment: Сейчас он выполняется синхронно, раньше была задержка для Explorer такого вида `await AwesomeWebBrowserControl.WaitAsync(5000);`

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, сам пошутил - сам посмеялся. Конечно решение не очень красивое, но зато теперь все работает. К сути

**Причина зависания:**

Поток awesomium_process (поток движка awesomium) потребляет все больше и больше памяти (причем сам движок винить не стоит, на некоторых сайтах все работает хорошо, в то время как другие съедают какое то непомерное количество памяти (1.5гб за 10 минут)). Т.к. движок написан под x86, при достижении предела адресации awesomium_process крашится (но не крашится сама форма приложения), в следствии чего наблюдается зависание без каких-либо явных ошибок.

**Решение (костыль):**

Пишется простенькая программа - лаунчер, в которой запускаются приложения-браузеры. В лаунчере нужно поставить флаг получения событий от процесса и подписаться на событие Exit:

```
Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
Process.Exited += Process_Exited;
```

И, если событие происходит, перезапускать приложение-браузер. В самом приложении-браузере я сделал что-то типа watchdog-таймера, в котором проверяется работоспособность браузера. И если в течении, например, 10 секунд таймер не был сброшен - приложение вырубает само себя.

Если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой: конечно лаунчер работает чуть сложнее, если по каким-либо причинам в некоторые промежутки времени приложение нельзя просто взять и вырубить (происходит какое-то атомарное действие), то нужно как то ему (браузер-приложению) сообщить, чтобы оно выключилось само, как только это можно будет сделать без логических ошибок. Я использовал простенький WCF-интерфейс:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICloser
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Shutdown();
}
```

Теперь вся эта система теперь работает 24/7 без ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Та же проблема. Но у меня один WebControl, который обновляется раз в 5 секунд по таймеру.
Добавил вот такую строчку в таймер

```
browser.RenderProcess.Refresh();
```

Загребаемая память процесса растет, но уже гораздо медленнее. 
Мне кажется, что он кеш собирает и копит с каждым обновлением. Способа подчищать не нашел.

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ. Да, памяти ест чуть меньше. Но зато стали появляться ошибки при возврате результата из `ExecuteJavascriptWithResult` (почему-то результат стал часто бывать пустым (пустой объект). 2 дня искал причину и оказалась она в рендере.. ппц. Лучше пусть ест память))